# How to join these tables? Is it possible?

Tags: mysql

Table articles stores articles id ant title values. Table similar adds extra articles with similar_id by matching article = similar table ID.

I'd better show output, its very hard to explain in words:

```
Article with id 3 -> Title3 Text3
when
Similar articles -> Title1(voteup,votedown), Title2(voteup,votedown)
```

because article table id = similar table id. ( 3 = 3[similar_id 1],3[similar_id 2]. )
And probably when article outputs similar articles id it has to back and take title of similar_id from first table.

-

```
Table Articles:

    ID     Title    text

    1      title1   text1
    2      title2   text2
    3      title3   text3

Table Similar:

    ID     Similar_ID   voteup votedown

    1          2          50      2
    2          3         1621    531
    3          1         ...     ...
    3          2         ...     ...
```

Comment: I wrote how output would look if I'd use article with ID 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, the `Similar_ID` field is a red herring here and shouldn't be included in the query:

```
SELECT articles.Title, similar.VoteUp, similar.VoteDown
FROM articles
JOIN similar ON articles.ID = similar.ID
WHERE articles.ID = 3
```

And to include similar titles (although I'm not quite sure how you want the data structured), you can do this:

```
SELECT articles.Title, similar.VoteUp, similar.VoteDown, similar_articles.Title AS SimilarTitle
FROM articles
JOIN similar ON articles.ID = similar.ID
JOIN articles similar_articles ON similar.Similar_ID = similar_articles.ID
WHERE articles.ID = 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) i've searched for this looong time